# Write pyspark dataframe to file keeping nested quotes, but not "outer" ones?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is there a way to preserve nested quotes in pyspark dataframe value when writing to file (in my case, a TSV) while also getting rid of the "outer" ones (ie. those that denote a string value in a column)?

```py
>>> dff = sparkSession.createDataFrame([(10,'this is "a test"'), (14,''), (16,'')], ["age", "comments"])
>>> dff.show()
+---+----------------+
|age|        comments|
+---+----------------+
| 10|this is "a test"|
| 14|                |
| 16|                |
+---+----------------+
>>> dff.write\
    .mode('overwrite')\
    .option("sep", "\t")\
    .option("quoteAll", "false")\
    .option("emptyValue", "").option("nullValue", "")\
    .csv('/tmp/test')
```

then

```sh
$ cat /tmp/test/part-000*
10  "this is \"a test\""
14  
16

# what I'd want to see is
10  this is "a test"
14  
16
# because I am later parsing based only on TAB characters, so the quote sequences are not a problem in that regard
```

Is there any way to write the dataframe in this desired format?

* as aside, more info about the args used can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#csv-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `escapeQuotes` option to `false`:

```
>>> dff = spark.createDataFrame([(10,'this is "a test"'), (14,''), (16,'')], ["age", "comments"])
>>> dff.show()
+---+----------------+                                                          
|age|        comments|
+---+----------------+
| 10|this is "a test"|
| 14|                |
| 16|                |
+---+----------------+

>>> dff.write\
...     .mode('overwrite')\
...     .option("sep", "\t")\
...     .option("quoteAll", "false")\
...     .option("emptyValue", "").option("nullValue", "")\
...     .option("escapeQuotes", "false").csv('/tmp/test')
>>>
```

```
➜  ~ cd /tmp/test           
➜  test ls
_SUCCESS                                                 part-00001-f702e661-15c2-4ab9-aef2-8dad5d923412-c000.csv part-00003-f702e661-15c2-4ab9-aef2-8dad5d923412-c000.csv
part-00000-f702e661-15c2-4ab9-aef2-8dad5d923412-c000.csv part-00002-f702e661-15c2-4ab9-aef2-8dad5d923412-c000.csv
➜  test cat part*         
10  this is "a test"
14  
16  
➜  test
```